# Lower image quality after paste two files

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

what I need:
- there are two images: a background (large) and a proifile pic (smaller)
- on background there is an oblique box, where I want to merge the profile pic

Code:

```
# open the profile pic
im = PIL.Image.open(pic)
# resize it to dim of oblique box
im = im.resize((picX, picY))

# this is the degree of oblique box
degree = 13.67

# open the background
bg = PIL.Image.open(bgsrc)
bgosize = bg.size
bginfo = bg.info


# first, I rotate the background to be paralell with profile pic
bg = bg.rotate(-degree, resample = PIL.Image.BILINEAR, expand = True)

# paste the profile pic to background
bg.paste(im, (px1, py1, px2, py2))

# rotate back to original orientation
bg = bg.rotate(degree, resample = PIL.Image.BILINEAR, expand = False)


# crop the rotated image, because it's greater than original size,
# after first rotate - coords are stored
bg.crop(bgx1, bgy1, bgx2, bgy2)

PIL.ImageFile.MAXBLOCK = bg.size[0] * bg.size[1]
bg.save(dst, quality = 250, optimize = True, **bginfo)
```

After this transform the result image is nubbly a litlebit...

How can I get a good qualtiy image?

Thanks:

a.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint 1: Use `Image.BICUBIC` instead of `Image.BILINEAR`. Unfortunately `rotate` does not accept `Image.ANTIALIAS` which would provide an even better result.

Hint 2: Instead of rotating the background and rotating it back later, rotate the image you want to paste.

Hint 3: Create an image in `'L'` format that is pure white and the same size as the image you're pasting. Rotate it the same way. Use it as a mask argument to `paste`.

---

I haven't tested this code but it should work. One question though, what is `quality = 250` supposed to accomplish? The [JPEG options](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/format-jpeg.htm) for example only accept values from 1 to 95.

```
# open the profile pic 
im = PIL.Image.open(pic) 
# resize it to dim of oblique box 
im = im.resize((picX, picY), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS) 

# this is the degree of oblique box 
degree = 13.67 

# open the background 
bg = PIL.Image.open(bgsrc) 
bgosize = bg.size 
bginfo = bg.info 

# create a copy of the profile that is all white
mask = PIL.Image.new('L', im.size, 0xff)

# rotate the profile and the mask
im = im.rotate(degree, resample = PIL.Image.BICUBIC, expand = True)
mask = mask.rotate(degree, resample = PIL.Image.BICUBIC, expand = True)

# paste the profile pic to background 
bg.paste(im, (px1, py1, px2, py2), mask) 

PIL.ImageFile.MAXBLOCK = bg.size[0] * bg.size[1] 
bg.save(dst, quality = 250, optimize = True, **bginfo)
```

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for the replies,

1: I've tried BILINEAR too - it has no effect.
2: If I rotate profile picture first, it will resized to a larger dimension, with black background - how can I rotate/transform a JPEG to tranparent PNG?
3: I will check the mask argument, if you have an example, I thank you :)

Comment: Hi Mark,thanks for the example.
If I save the images on-the-fly after im.rotate and mask.rotate, they are also nubbly too... So, even if I open the background and save it from PIL, it will nubbly too.

My another comment: when the cr object (instead of im) is masked, it has a black background - how can I create a transparent background? Many thanks:

Answer (score 1):

Try bicubic interpolation? If that doesn't help, try making the image larger (say, 2x or even 4x size), rotating, then downsizing to the original dimensions afterward.

Comment: I've tried - no changes. Larger image is not solution, because profile picture will come from users - I can't (don't want) to expect larger image from them.

Comment: @airween, I think what he's suggesting is resize up, rotate, resize back down to original size.

Comment: Ahm', so, sorry, I missunderstood - well, I will check it out, thanks.